# ftp_get(): Transfer failed

Tags: php

This is the code that I am using

```
    <?php
// connect and login to FTP server
$ftp_server = "ftp_server";

$ftp_conn = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("Could not connect to $ftp_server");
ftp_pasv($ftp_conn, TRUE);
ftp_set_option($ftp_conn, FTP_TIMEOUT_SEC, 2800);
$ftp_username="ftp_username";
$ftp_userpass="ftp_userpass";

$login = ftp_login($ftp_conn, $ftp_username, $ftp_userpass);

$local_file = "local_file";
$server_file = "server_file";


if (ftp_get($ftp_conn, $local_file, $server_file, FTP_BINARY))
  {
  echo "Successfully written to ".$local_file;
  }
else
  {
  echo "Error downloading ".$server_file;
  }

// close connection
ftp_close($ftp_conn);
```

I get the same error all the time-

**"Warning: ftp_get(): Transfer failed in myfile.php on line 33
Error downloading server_file"**

I try to see if the file that I am trying to get is the right one so I used 
this code-

```
$res = ftp_size($ftp_conn, $server_file);

if ($res != -1) {
    echo "size of $server_file is $res bytes";
} else {
    echo "couldn't get the size";
}
```

I get the file size so the file is exist. The file is about 11MB so the size of the file not suppose to be an issue.

I added the lines :

```
ftp_pasv($ftp_conn, TRUE);
ftp_set_option($ftp_conn, FTP_TIMEOUT_SEC, 2800);
```

After searching solutions on the web but the results are the same with or without those lines...

Any ideas?

Cheerz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `ftp_pasv()` after `ftp_login()`, not before.  Check the return value of the function call to see if it succeeds.